# Example of compact fiber bundle with noncompact fibers

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, fibre-bundles

This is a cross post of [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4006624/272127) somehow:

Is there any example of compact fiber bundle $E$ with noncompact fibers $F$?

Obviously if the base space $B$ is $T_1$ then there is no such example.

Comment: Hint: use compactness of the base $B$ to show that $E$ is trivialised over some nonempty closed subset $Z \subseteq B$.